# Tensor product of two localizations is the fraction field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

Let $A$ be a commutative domain with unit, and let $\mathfrak{p},\mathfrak{q}$ be two different maximal ideals of $A$.
Then we know $A_\mathfrak{p}\otimes_A A_\mathfrak{q}\cong S^{-1}A$ as $A$-algebras, where $S:=\{xy|\ x\in A\setminus \mathfrak{p}, y\in A\setminus \mathfrak{q}\}.$

I have two questions:
(i) In general do we know whether $S^{-1}A$ is the fraction field of $A$?
I have known this if $A$ is a Dedekind domain by noting that $A_\mathfrak{p}$ is a DVR.
(ii)  Do we have $S=A\setminus\{0\}$ in general?

Answer (score 1):

In general, the answer to both of your questions is no. It may happen that there are elements of $A$ not in $S$: for instance, if $A=k[x,y]$, $p=(x,y)$, and $q=(x,y-1)$ for a field $k$, then $x^n\notin S$ for any $n>0$. To see this, suppose $x^n=ab$ for $a\in A\setminus (x,y)$ and $b\in A\setminus (x,y-1)$. Then the evaluation map $k[x,y]\to k[y]$ by $x\mapsto 0$ sends $x^n\mapsto 0$ but $a,b$ map to nonzero elements.

We may extend this to note that any element of any prime ideal contained in both $p$ and $q$ remains outside of $S$ - as a Dedekind domain is of dimension one, the only prime ideal contained in $p$ and $q$ is $(0)$, explaining your initial findings.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your patient reply

Comment: But can you prove (ii) for Dedekind domain?

Comment: I thought you proved that for Dedekind domains already?

Comment: But I have not proved (ii) directly since I use the fact that A_p is a DVR.

Comment: My answer shows that (ii) is false in general. Can you state clearly the claim you want to prove but cannot?

Comment: I want to prove $S=A\setminus\{0\} $ if $A$ is a Dedekind domain.

Comment: After thinking about it for a day, I'm unsure either way - it is potentially possible for $A_p\otimes A_q=Frac(A)$ without $S=A\setminus 0$, and I don't have a good idea for a proof or a counterexample. Sorry I don't have anything more substantial to say.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your seriously treatment , I will open a new question.